# alertView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have main view with links to different viewcontrollers. One of my views has some form fields, when they update successfully, it calls an `UIAlertView` to notify the user. When the user dismisses it the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is called and I `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` back to my main view.

The problem I am having is when I do this it does not call the `viewDidLoad` method. I have variables that need to update, can somebody tell me what is being called. I cannot find anything so that I can make the updates.

Answer (score 1):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called when the view controller becomes visible. You can check if your data has been updated in those functions and update your view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and flexible way to handle this situation is to expose a method from your controller to reset it.  This way, in any unforeseen scenario, you can always call this method and know that your values are being set:

```
@interface MyController
- (void)reset;
@end

@implementation MyController
- (void)reset{
    //set some defaults
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [self reset];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear{ //<--If you want to reset your values every time the view is about to appear
   [self reset];
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear{ //<--If you want to reset your values every time the view is either dismissed, covered, or hidden
   [self reset];
}
@end
```

Then in your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex==0) { //whatever your situation is
         //dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
         [self.myController reset];
    }
}
```

Some additional reading:  [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will be called once after the view has been loaded, which might be more than once for the life of the controller.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I was thinking the same thing about a reset function, so now it is controlled by  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated and it is called every time as you all stated.There is a Control Panel View and a Form View so the self.myController reset did not fit in here.